# PL/SQL How to display a custom text when no row is returned

Tags: sql, stored-procedures, plsql, oracle-sqldeveloper, procedure

I have this assignment where i have to get an overview from specialisations with a procedure from all the employees called "personeel","pers" or "per".(dutch tables and attributes)

If they don't have any specialisation, then it needs to return "no specialisations found".

The problem is when i use cursors (which is the way we NEED to solve this) and I use a for loop, I can't seem to test if the person has no specialisations. I also don't really know how to search this on the internet. All i seem to be finding is cursor attriubutes but that doesn't work.

This is my code (in sqldeveloper)

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE OVERZICHT_SPECIALISATIES AS
```

This cursor contains all the employees

```
cursor cur_per is
select voornaam, achternaam
from personeel;
```

This cursor contains the employee's their specialisation but if they have none it just returns no rows found which is what i want to test on

```
cursor cur_spec (p_vn PERSONEEL.VOORNAAM%type, p_an PERSONEEL.ACHTERNAAM%type) is
select p.code, s.titel, p.datum_behaald
from pers_specialisaties p, personeel per, specialisaties s
where per.persnr = p.persnr
and p.code = s.code
and voornaam = p_vn
and achternaam = p_an
group by p.code,s.titel, p.datum_behaald;

BEGIN
for r_per in cur_per
loop
dbms_output.put_line(r_per.voornaam || ' ' || r_per.achternaam);
dbms_output.put_line('---------------------------');

for r_spec in cur_spec (r_per.voornaam, r_per.achternaam)
loop
```

This is the IF statement were I test, but it doesn't seem to work

```
  IF (cur_spec%NOTFOUND)
  THEN
  dbms_output.put_line('no specialisations found');
  ELSE
  dbms_output.put_line(r_spec.code || '    ' || r_spec.titel || ' ' 
                        || r_spec.datum_behaald);
  END IF;
end loop;
dbms_output.put_line(' ');
end loop;

END OVERZICHT_SPECIALISATIES;
```

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do this with `left join`.  In general, you should use explicit `join` syntax -- it is more powerful than commas.  In fact, follow a simple rule:  never use commas in the `from` clause.

```
select p.code, coalesce(s.titel, 'no specialisations found') as titel, p.datum_behaald
from personeel per left join
     pers_specialisaties p
     on per.persnr = p.persnr left join
     specialisaties s
     on p.code = s.code
where per.voornaam = p_vn and per.achternaam = p_an;
```

This keeps all rows in `personneel`.  If there is no matching `s.titel`, it gets the string that you want there.

I am not sure what the `group by` was doing.  I don't see a reason why your query would be returning duplicate values.  You can put it back in if necessary.

I'm also assuming that `voornam` and `achternaam` come from the `per` table.

Comment: the group by was still a leftover from an earlier test with a count. Thanks for noticing :)

Normally I do inner joins but we had to rewrite this code from a few months ago when i didn't do that yet.

Comment: I tested it with inner joins, it doesn't seem to work anymore then.  Why isn't this possible ?

Comment: @kevin . . . Because inner joins filter out non-matching rows.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a flag that you set to false for each person, and then set to true inside the specialities loop - indicating that at least one speciality was found. Then test afterwards whether it is true or false for that person; if it is false then you didn't go into the loop, so there were no specialities:

```
declare
   found_record_flag boolean;
   ...
begin
  for r_per in cur_per
  loop
    dbms_output.put_line(r_per.voornaam || ' ' || r_per.achternaam);
    dbms_output.put_line('---------------------------');

    found_record_flag := false;
    for r_spec in cur_spec (r_per.voornaam, r_per.achternaam)
    loop
      found_record_flag := true;
      dbms_output.put_line(r_spec.code || '    ' || r_spec.titel || ' ' 
                            || r_spec.datum_behaald);
    end loop;

    if found_record_flag = false then
      dbms_output.put_line('no specialisations found');
    end if;

    dbms_output.put_line(' ');
  end loop;
...
```

Your second cursor is really assuming that no two people have the same combination of first and last name. It would be better to include `persnr` in the select list for the first clause, and only pass that in as the cursor parameter; then the second cursor wouldn't need to query the `personeel` table again:

```
cursor cur_per is
select persnr, voornaam, achternaam
from personeel;

cursor cur_spec (p_persnr personeel.persnr%type) is
select ps.code, s.titel, ps.datum_behaald
from pers_specialisaties ps
join specialisaties s
on s.code = ps.code
where ps.persnr = p_persnr;
```

I'm also not sure why you're grouping the values, unless you were getting duplicates because of a duplicate name. It shouldn't be necessary. And then later:

```
    for r_spec in cur_spec (r_per.persnr)
    loop
```

Comment: Thanks for the input, I didn't know he didn't enter the loop when there were no records found. The group by was still a leftover from an earlier test with a count. Thanks for noticing :)

This Also works Thanks !

Comment: @Kevin - with the outer-join version you still need to hit the `personeel` table a second time; even if you really want to do that, I'd still pass the `persnr` rather than the names, so you know you're looking for a single person - in case there are duplicate names.

Comment: Well the assignment wants us to search on names. I know it really isn't the best way. But if that's what the teacher wants us to do... He has made it so that there are no duplicate names.

Comment: @Kevin - fair enough. Odd, but can't argue with requirements, sometimes.